# Looped update SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to define a stored procedure inSQL Server with a loop to create a bridge table between old and newest product codes. I am not an expert in SQL and I'm having some trouble...

I already have a source table that contains all product codes changes, However, I need to create the table that contains the relation of all OLD product codes with the NEWEST product code.

The source table is like:

```
PRD_OLD   ----   PRD_NEW
00001         ----    00003
00002         ----    00003
00003         ----    00004
00004         ----    00005
00006         ----    00007
```

It can be seen that products 1 and 2 correspond to product 3. Then 3 corresponds to 4 and then 4 corresponds to 5, so the newest product ID for 1, 2, 3 and 4 should be 5.

The output table then should be:

```
PRD_OLD   ----   PRD_NEW
00001         ----    00005
00002         ----    00005
00003         ----    00005
00004         ----    00005
00006         ----    00007
```

Note: in my table the Codes are codes with both letters and numbers (GUIDS) so using maximums won't work...

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select prd_old, prd_new, 1 as lev
      from source
      union all
      select cte.prd_old, s.prd_new, lev + 1
      from cte join
           source s
           on cte.prd_new = s.prd_old
     )
select t.*
from (select cte.*, max(lev) over (partition by prd_old) as max_lev
      from cte
     ) t
where lev = max_lev;
```